# pycharm vim extension: How to remap “k+j” to Escape key?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm, vscodevim

I wanted to know how I can use the same setting in pycharm as in VSCode.

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": ["k", "j"],
        "after": ["<Esc>"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the solution.
Adding `inoremap kj <ESC>` to the `.ideavimrc` helped.

Thanks, GitHub: @ikenox for the help.